# Mapping arbitrary objects to indices

Tags: string, indexing, bigdata

Let's assume that we have some objects (strings, for example). It is well known that working with indices (i.e. with numbers 1,2,3...) is much more convenient than with arbitrary objects.

Is there any common way of assigning an index for each object? One can create a hash_map and store an index in the value, but that will be memory-expensive when the number of objects is too high to be placed into the memory.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean an *array*?

Comment: No, I mean a function F: Objects -> Indices. Giving an object I would like to get a number from 0 to #objects without collisions and without storing all objects in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the string objects in a sorted file.
This way, you are not storing the objects in memory.

Your mapping function can search for the required object in the sorted file.
You can create a hash map to optimize the search.